# Configuration x86_64-unknown-cygwin not supported

Tags: gcc, cygwin, downgrade

I have installed Cygwin with GCC 11.3, but I recognized that I need to downgrade GCC to 4.7.2.
The gmp-5.0.5, mpfr-3.1.1 and mpc-1.0.1 were successfully installed, but when I installed the gcc-4.7.2, the error occurred:

```
...
checking whether madvise is declared... yes
checking for struct tms... yes
checking for clock_t... yes
checking for F_SETLKW... yes
checking if mkdir takes one argument... no
*** Configuration x86_64-unknown-cygwin not supported
make[2]: *** [Makefile:3896: configure-stage1-gcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/username/gcc-4.7.2-obj/gcc-4.7.2-build'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:15763: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/username/gcc-4.7.2-obj/gcc-4.7.2-build'
make: *** [Makefile:898: all] Error 2
```

Any hint on this? and how should it be done instead? Thanks in advance

Comment: The conftest.exe is identified as a malware, the system blocked conftest.exe, does this matter?

Comment: unblock it, and sent it to a on-line virus checker to reassure yourself that it is safe.

Comment: why you need to downgrade the GCC ? Compiling the GCC is a long effort probably not worth the effort. About the malware false positive open a ticket with the Antivirus supplier, usually they have a web page for that scope